# Combine lists to get list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, append, extend

```
aa = ['a']
bb = ['b']
aa.extend(bb)
['a', 'b']
```

In the example above, I would like to combine 2 lists to get list of lists, `[['a'], ['b']]`, but `extend` does not allow that. How can I achieve it in python?

Comment: `cc = [aa, bb]`

Comment: You could declare a container first: `c = []`, then append as many other lists as you want. `c.append(aa)`, `c.append(bb)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a list of lists, you could go about this way:

```
>> aa = ['a']
>> bb = ['b']
>> cc = []
>> cc.append(aa)
>> cc
[['a']]
>> cc.append(bb)
>> cc
[['a'], ['b']]
```

Or another way could be:

```
>> dd = list((aa,bb))
>> dd
[['a'], ['b']]
```

I suggest using the append keyword as it makes it easier to use it within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done simply using:

new_list = [aa, bb]